# Python 3.x Editing text areas and copying from fields and not open browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, browser, splinter

Had a look [Here](https://www.google.com.au/search?espv=2&q=how%20to%20copy%20text%20from%20a%20field%20python%20from%20webpage&oq=how%20to%20copy%20text%20from%20a%20field%20python%20from%20webpage&gs_l=serp.3...6848.9312.0.9397.13.10.0.0.0.0.336.833.2-2j1.3.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..13.0.0.aHAuNOmBeg0)

No specific answers to my question

I am using splinter and here's what I put into the shell and what returned.

```
>>> from splinter.browser import Browser
>>> browser = Browser()
>>> browser.visit('http://www.timestampgenerator.com/tools/md5-generator/')
>>> browser.fill('source','hello')
>>> browser.find_by_id('submit').click()
>>> ans = browser.find_by_id('result')
>>> print(ans)
[<splinter.driver.webdriver.WebDriverElement object at 0x00000010DECEE3C8>]
```

The copying didn't work very well. You can visit [This page](http://www.timestampgenerator.com/tools/md5-generator/) To get an idea of what I'm in against. What i want to ASK
How can I delete text from a certain field, so if I put hello after doing

```
browser.fill('source','hello')
```

I might be wanting to do it again without refreshing the page so I need to delete text. How to do that? Also you can see that my attempt to copy text with

```
>>> ans = browser.find_by_id('result')
>>> print(ans)
[<splinter.driver.webdriver.WebDriverElement object at 0x00000010DECEE3C8>]
```

failed, would like to know how to do that. Also finally how can I do this operation without opening firefox windowed, perhaps simply as a background process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the text from the 'result' element, you need to print the value of the selected element.

```
print(ans.value)
```

You can make a list with entries you want to fill the 'source' element with, and use a for loop to go through the list. You don't need to delete the previous entry, fill will overwrite the contents it seems.

Here is an example, had to put in a 1 second wait_time in my case for it to not grab the wrong 'result'.

```
from splinter import Browser

with Browser() as browser:
    browser.visit('http://www.timestampgenerator.com/tools/md5-generator/')
    entries = ['hello', 'goodbye']
    for item in entries:
        browser.fill('source', item)
        browser.find_by_id('submit').click()
        browser.is_text_present('result', wait_time=1)
        ans = browser.find_by_id('result')
        print(ans.value)
```

For a headless webbrowser (not opening a window), [check out the splinter documentation](http://splinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html?#headless-drivers). You'll need to get a webdriver of your choice.